# Drupal Captcha showing on TOP and not at bottom?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, captcha

I've never had this problem. When I enable "administration links", the "place captcha here" always appears at the bottom of a content type, but for some reason it is now appearing ABOVE the title field. How do I get it below again?

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Just install the latest dev version of CAPTCHA